# A variant of Slutsky theorem for matrices: $Z_n\to^d N(0,I_d)$ and $T_nT_n^\top\to^P C$. When is it true that $T_nZ_n\to^d N(0,C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Consider a sequence $Z_n$ of random vectors in $R^d$ such that $Z_n\to N(0_d,I_d)$ in distribution.

Consider a sequence of random matrices $T_n\in R^{d\times d}$, not independent of $Z_n$, such that $T_nT_n^\top\to C$ for a deterministic positive semi-definite $C\in R^{d\times d}$.

I am interested in whether $T_n Z_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0_d, C)$.

*Remark* 1: This is Slutsky's theorem if $d=1$.

*Remark 2*: If $T_n\to^d A$ and $C=AA^T$, then we may apply the continuous mapping theorem to the function $f(T,z)=Tz$. But here we only assume convergence of $T_nT_n^\top$ to $C$.

**$T_n Z_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0_d, C)$ not true.** A counterexample is as follows: $T_n$ is a rotation in $O(d)$ for all $n$ such that the first row is $Z_n/\|Z_n\|$, so that $T_nT_n^\top = I_d$ but $T_n Z_n$ has zero in coordinates $2,3,...,d$.

So let us add another assumption to avoid this rotation situation:

**Question**: Is it always true that $T_n Z_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0_d, C)$ provided that $T_n$ is lower triangular with $1$ on the diagonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your last question is positive. Indeed, if $C$ is positive definite (which is your implicit assumption here), then the Cholesky factor $A$ in $C = AA^T$ depends on $C$ continuously, so $T_n\to A$ in distribution (and actually in probability, since $A$ is non-random).

Comment: Very insightful. Many thanks. I posted a follow-up question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800575/yet-another-variant-of-slutskys-theorem-for-matrices-if-z-n-to-n0-d-s-and